# convert multiple Query String to seo friendly url in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have url Like `http://somesite.com/packagemenu.php?conname=domestic-tours-packages&consubname=kerala-tours-packages`

Now, i want to make it seo friendly with php code or htaccess rewriterule

my output should be look like this

```
http://somesite.com/domestic-tours-packages/kerala-tours-packages
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply apply the rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$    packagemenu.php?conname=$1&consubname=$2    [NC,L]
```

Comment: can i test that in staging website because my htaccess are not working i've tried this but without [NC,L].i've tried this htaccess code but it's not working.

Comment: @RushabhShah It does work for me. I don't know in which way you way its not working. Have you entered `http://somesite.com/domestic-tours-packages/kerala-tours-packages` in the URL?

Comment: Hey thank you!! it worked!! but css and js are not loading!

Comment: what if there is multiple pages like packagemenu.php then somepage.php ? i have tried RewriteRule    ^([^/\.]+)$    packagedetails.php?pid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$    packagemenu.php?conname=$1&consubname=$2    [NC,L]

Comment: Actually this is another question, you need to provide on which condition it needs to be redirected to packagedetails and for which condition, it needs to be redirected to packagemenu.

Comment: 1)for packagedetails i want url like somesite.com/kerala-tour  and 2)for packagemenu.php?conname=domestic-tours-packages&consubname=kerala-tours-packages what we did was perfect.or we can have perfect url for e.g.: http://somesite.com/domestic-tours-packages/kerala-tours-packages/kerala-tour

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect from querystring to short url, Try the following

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /packagemenu.php\?conname=([^&]+)&consubname=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [NC,L,R]

#skip the rule if the request is for dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 #skip the rule if the request is for file
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 #rewrite any other request  to "/packagemenu.php?" 
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /packagemenu.php?conname=$1&consubname=$2 [NC,L]
```

shortest way to do it is as above!

Comment: trying this one!! thanx for reply!!

Comment: @rushabhshah the accepted answer is not the shortest way ,its a half way to do this rewriting. You can still access your url with query strings.ex : http://example.com/file.php?q=foo is still redirecting to http://example.com/file.php?q=foo, google will index both urls. my code is a little diffrent and complete ,it redirects http://example.com/file.php?q=foo to http://example.com/foo SEF, and search engine will index just 1 http://example.com/foo not http://example.com/file.php?q=foo

Comment: yes but it's not working! i can still open querystring when i injected this code in htaccess and i also want the same for single querystring i customized this code but it didn't work!